# QPlainTextEdit truncate history linewise

Tags: qt, logging, qplaintextedit, log-rotation

I have a GUI application whose main part is a [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qplaintextedit.html). It is used to display a log of the application, and as such the associated text grows line by line ad infinitum.

As the application is intended to run very long, I need to limit the memory that will be allocated for this log. Therefore I want to have some `maxNumLines` or `maxNumCharacters` parameter that will make sure the history will be truncated when reached, i.e. the head lines will be removed as new lines are appended (a.k.a. *log rotation*).

To achieve this I found the functions

```
// get the associated text
QString toPlainText () const

// set the associated text
void setPlainText ( const QString & text )
```

Therefore something like this untested code would probably do the trick:

```
QString &tmp = pte.toPlainText();
while (tmp.size() > maxNumCharacters) {
  // remove lines from the head of the string until the desired size is reached
  // removes nothing if "\n" could not be found
  tmp.remove(0, tmp.indexOf("\n")+1);
}
pte.setPlainText( tmp );
```

Is this the way to go to remove the first line(s) from the `QPlainTextEdit`? Are there probably other Qt Text GUI elements that would better fit to this task (set a maximum number of lines and truncate at the head of the list), e.g. somehow display a `QStringList` in which I could store the lines (s.t. I could easily `erase(0)`)?

Or does the QPlainTextEdit eventually implement such upper bound for the size of the associated QString after all?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparantly the property `maximumBlockCount` is exactly what I need:

> If you want to limit the total number of paragraphs in a `QPlainTextEdit`, as it is for example useful in a log viewer, then you can use the `maximumBlockCount` property. The combination of `setMaximumBlockCount()` and `appendPlainText()` turns `QPlainTextEdit` into an efficient viewer for log text.

For reference:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#maximumBlockCount-prop

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was previously using cursor based insertion, but I discovered that `append*` methods will provide much higher performances.

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem a months back, and I ended up using a `QListView`.  Although using the model/view/delegate architecture is a bit more fiddly, it scales much better in the long run.  For example once the basic architecture is in place, adding a filter that displays only error or warning entries becomes trivial, or creating a delegate so that the background of error entries are painted red is also straightforward.

Comment: see also: `QListWidget`